# find an error in installation of phonegap plugin in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cordova

[image]I am a beginner in phonegap.
I want to install it in eclipse but I always get error message: I use **Windows 7, Eclipse Kepler, the latest version of the Android SDK, the latest version of ADT** and finally to phonegap eclipse plugin C 'is the link:

http://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/tags/r1.2/download

Installing the Android SDK and ADT is easily

Eclipse displays a message that it has encountered errors while installing phonegap eclipse plugin.
Help me please!
Installation is aborted of 49% of completion with this error:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:

```
(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, perand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.mozilla.javascript,1.7.2.v201005080400.
MD5 hash is not as expected. 
Expected: 8785860e8f2a2a43fe10dd8b9eb334b6 and found  7ab8a5d6da46b081c83bfc81e7c880e6.
```